# Can anyone paste code for detcting memory leaks in win ce 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

Hey i need code for detecting memory leaks in win ce. I am using Visual c++. Can any one give please?

Comment: Nobody will provide you code for this. Try searching in Google for tools that will do this for you.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I have valgrind. But my client wants code for detecting memoryleak. And I am at my delivery date So i am asking for code,

Comment: There are built in heap checkers for most C librarys, they can only warn for inconsistency e.g double free, invalid free etc. But never catch buffer overflow. Memory leakage is detected through marking. E.g mark heap, run request/program flow, monitor objects not free'd.

Answer (score 2):

- You can see Sue Loe's blog about memory tools for Windows CE: [A Tour of Windows CE Memory Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/ce_base/archive/2006/01/11/511883.aspx).
- Here is the reference for Application Verifier for Windows CE 6: [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee505017.aspx)
- Here is [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446904.aspx) about Application Verifier 5 by Douglas Boiling. Most of it should be relevant for Windows CE 6 as well if I am not mistaken.
- To get Application Verifier you need to download Windows CE 6 (Platform Builder 6). Free for 6 months: [Download Windows CE 6](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/default.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
void *my_debug_malloc(size_t size)
{
  void *p = malloc(size);
  printf("malloced %d bytes at %08X\n", size, p);
  return p;
}

void my_debug_free(void *p)
{
  printf("About to free ? bytes at %08X\n", p);
  free(p);
}

#define malloc my_debug_malloc
#define free my_debug_free

// The rest of your program...
```

calloc, realloc is left as an exercise :)

Actually, I have debugged a lot of code using this method. But then we bought in [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) and productivity boosted...